# React - Three.js - GLTFLoader "JSON.parse error"

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

so whenever I want to import a model via GLTFLoader locally I get this error:

**JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

but when I try it via a link it works.

The link I tried with is:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/39255/ladybug.gltf

I tested the models I used in the official three.js-Editor and even exported them from there to get a "clean" gltf model. I also saved the content of the link in a gltf file and it didnt work neither.

This is my code:

```
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
    
    async function run() {
      try {
        var loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.crossOrigin = true;
        loader.load(
          "./scene.gltf",
          //"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/39255/ladybug.gltf",
          function (data) {
            var object = data.scene;
            object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    
            scene.add(object);
          }
        );
    
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

run();
```

Comment: What are you using to run your local server? I have a hunch you're running into [security restrictions](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) and you have to set up a local server to deliver your GLTF assets like a web server would.

Comment: So I cannot import them via a simple path? I will try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marquizzo said: You have to run a local server for the models. You cannot import them via a path normally, because of security restrictions.